# Which federal 2024 U.S. election candidates support a federal abortion ban?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, abortion

Which federal 2024 U.S. election candidates support a federal ban on all abortions? Has a study been done on this?

Comment: Apparently Pence but not Trump https://apnews.com/article/abortion-federal-ban-trump-gop-2024-20586bbb64a511030ef58290e98f99f0 The piece is a little vague though. DeSantis would support a 15-week one https://apnews.com/article/abortion-republicans-desantis-trump-bdccde60987da99018bf3abcbafedea0 So, I guess that [the term] needs to be a parameter in any attempt to summarize.

Comment: Given how much of a hot button topic a Federal abortion ban is, even for Republicans, I'm going to guess some candidate's positions will be different depending on who they're talking to.

Comment: There are 470 seats to be filled in Nov 2024. Most of the field will not be narrowed until after the primaries (most by Aug 2024). Filing [deadlines for the primaries](https://ballotpedia.org/State_and_federal_candidate_filing_deadlines_for_2024) extend into Jul 2024. Before the primaries, there could be 1500-2500 candidates. After the primaries, there would still be about 1000. Either the question is too broad, or is not timely asked, or both. There might be something next Sep-Oct, just not now.